# How google track whether code is pasted on that particular site?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am on project in which user will give there site info. I will give him a widget code which he has to paste on his site.

On normal third party widget, if a user won't paste the code than it is his loss but in my project , if the code is not pasted , user won't affected rather its my loss. So I want a mechanism in which i could check if the code is pasted or not.

After a long search, I got clear view of what i want.

1. A mechanism/function which will check whether request from all the website(stored in my database) coming or not? If not receiving from any site , it will do some action.
2. A way so that that function always run in my server.

I too searched a lot and i find that my second question can be done with CRON job on the linux server but its the only way or any more secure way is there?[I only get to know about but don't know to apply that.]

We could take a example of Google Analytics. After adding a basic info, google gives us a code which he said to paste in our site. So how google checks whether the user has pasted the code or not? Is there any most secured way of doing this?

*[FOR EASE]* The flow of the project is --

USER SIGNUP ----> GIVE INFORMATION ABOUT THEIR SITE ---> GET THE CODE (javascript widget code) TO BE PASTED ---> GET INFORMATION FOR MY SITE FOR SOME ACTION

but if code is not pasted within specific time, user will get error in its dashboard.

For all this as a backend language, i am using PHP. Is there any other language is required or any other language which can make the task easy?

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your responsibility as a developer to ensure that the user has inserted the code on  their site.   It is your responsibility to ensure that your application displays an appropriate error message in the event that they nave not done so.

That's about all google does.  If they don't detect any incoming data they check the site you have entered to see if the snippet is there if not they show an error.

You haven't mentioned what your wigget does but if its not sending data to you.  You could check once a day to see if it exists or not.

Comment: @DalmTo , my widget just send a data from the site . My question now is how to detect all incoming request ? I can't find any secure way ?

Comment: If they are accessing your system i am sure that you can detect when they are accessing it.

Comment: @DalmTo, No , I want it check it every single moment ?

Comment: @DalmTo ,They are accessing my system with the third party widget

Comment: I am sure that google also check it every single moment .